# Java Thread join problem

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, eclipse-rcp

```
public void setGifImage(InputStream inputStream) {
        checkWidget();
        if (thread != null) {
            thread.stopRunning();
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();

        try {
            loader.load(inputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.image = null;
            return;
        }

        if (loader.data[0] != null){
            System.out.println("set to new picture");
            this.image = new Image(this.getDisplay(), loader.data[0]);
        }

        if (loader.data.length > 1) {
            System.out.println("start animation");
            thread = new GifThread(loader);
            thread.start();
        }else{
            System.out.println("paint static picture");
        }

        redraw();
    }
```

the thread :

```
private class GifThread extends Thread {

        private int imageNumber = 0;
        private ImageLoader loader = null;
        private boolean run = true;

        public GifThread(ImageLoader loader) {
            this.loader = loader;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (run) {
                int delayTime = loader.data[imageNumber].delayTime;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delayTime * 10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (!GifCLabel.this.isDisposed()) {
                    // if a asynchronous thread is running, this new runnable will be queued
                    GifCLabel.this.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (!GifCLabel.this.isDisposed()) {
                                imageNumber = imageNumber == loader.data.length - 1 ? 0 : imageNumber + 1;
                                if (!GifCLabel.this.image.isDisposed())
                                    GifCLabel.this.image.dispose();
                                ImageData nextFrameData = loader.data[imageNumber];
                                System.out.println("set to frame " + imageNumber);
                                GifCLabel.this.image = new Image(GifCLabel.this.getDisplay(), nextFrameData);
                                GifCLabel.this.redraw();
                            } else
                                stopRunning();
                        }
                    });
                } else
                    stopRunning();
            }
        }

        public void stopRunning() {
            run = false;
        }
    }
```

the output :

```
2011-08-10 03:44:24 DEBUG  - 日志服务Ready!
2011-08-10 03:44:28 DEBUG  - current is null
2011-08-10 03:44:28 DEBUG  - found : amarsoft.dbmp.function.ui.FunctionListPage@1079ff
2011-08-10 03:44:28 DEBUG  - can go back ? false
2011-08-10 03:44:28 DEBUG  - can go forward ? false
set to new picture
start animation
2011-08-10 03:44:28 DEBUG  - 尝试连接至 - jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/credit 驱动配置：MySQL 驱动类：com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1f7abae 连接属性：{user=root, password=root}
set to frame 1
set to frame 2
set to frame 3
set to frame 4
[amarsoft.dbmp.function.ui.FunctionListPage$1@29f93b, amarsoft.dbmp.function.ui.FunctionView$1@1a998c7]
set to new picture
paint static picture
set to frame 5
```

I wonder why the thread still run after thread.join()? As I know, thread.join() wait thread to die,but you can see the last line in output, thread run after die...

Comment: Are you sure that the thread you are joining is the same thread that you are seeing the log from? In other words, that there are no extra threads created? (you should make the method synchronized)

Comment: thanks for concern. which method to be synchronized ? Will that also fix my problem as Max's answer ? Although my problem is fixed, I want to learn more about threading :D

Comment: Max and I are both in the idea that the thread that you join is not the one doing the work. My idea that was perhaps your setGifImage method was being concurrently accessed; it this is true it may happen that a thread was joined two times and one thread is created that is not joined. If you are sure that your method is not called concurrently then nothing needs to be changed; elsewhere you can make it synchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you thread calls `getDisplay().asyncExec()` which basically sends event to UI thread to execute the Runnable that prints `"set to frame "`.

Better to use `syncExec()` and check `run` variable status inside Runnable too.

Another hints:

1. it's not a good idea to catch `InterruptedException` and do nothing.
2. call `interrupt` inside `stopRunnable()`
3. check `run` variable status *after* `sleep` ends.

Cheers,
Max